# sort substrings of filenames, giving unique values

Tags: powershell

FWIW - I had fun "developing" this simple routine which will list the unique artists among a listing of several hundred files in a single directory of MP3 files

Based on pattern "artist - title.mp3"

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {($_.basename -split ("-"))[0]} | Select-Object -unique
```

What I would like to do now is have a count next to each unique name (i.e. Duke Ellington - 4  Doris Day - 6

Not sure how to do this but it is probably very simple. Was tryng to use the group statement, but no luck

Bill Clark, Windham,VT

Comment: I'd take a look at hashtables.. and maintain counts in them. https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2016-11-06-powershell-hashtable-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about/#what-is-a-hashtable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all your files follow that pattern:

```
Get-ChildItem -File |
    Group-Object -Property {$_.BaseName.Split('-')[0]}
```

This will automatically group all the strings returned from the previous item in the pipeline.

---

Then you can do additional fun things with this:

```
Get-ChildItem -File |
    Group-Object -Property {$_.BaseName.Split('-')[0]} |
    ForEach-Object {
        $dir = "$([IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($_.Group[0].FullName))\$($_.Name)\"
        if (-not (Test-Path -Path $dir -PathType Container)) {
            New-Item -Path $dir -ItemType Directory
        }

        foreach ($file in $_.Group) {
            $file | Copy-Item -Destination $dir -Force
        }
}
```

And now all your songs are sorted by artist in folders.

Comment: Once more - the answers are fabulous, and your solution does exactly what I was looking for ... learning so much, and thanks !